# Creating a python script to backup new files, python 2.7

Tags: python

Here's what I'm trying to do:

For each specified file in source location, go through it and copy any file that exists in this folder tree but doesn't exist in its respective destination location and paste it into that respective destination location.

Here's what I have so far:

```
import os, shutil

src = 'C:\Users\Bobby\\'
dst = 'C:\Users\Bobby\Desktop\\'

folders = []
folders.append('texts')

for folder in folders:
    if not os.path.exists(src + folder):
        continue
    else:
        try:
            os.chdir(dst)
            if not os.path.exists(dst + folder):
                os.makedirs(folder)
                files = open(src + folder)
                for _file in files:
                    pass
                    #shutil.copy2(src + folder + _file, dst + folder)
        except:
            sys.exit(0)
```

Comment: This sounds like a job for [rsync](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync).

Comment: And the question is? (And yes, as said above, rsync would be fit, unless you chose Python for educational purposes.)

Comment: Don't use `os.chdir()` as it changes global state and can lead to interesting problems when the current working directory ends up to be something different than other parts of the program expect it to be. Don't use ”naked” `except:` without any explicit exception(s) you want and can handle in that suite. Ending the program with no clue as to why is also bad practice. That leaves almost no chance to debug or for the user to change something, e.g. access rights, in order to make the program work.

Answer (score 0):

The below code can backup the files from a user specified directory to a user specified zip file in a preferred location using python (It has a user interface as well)

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import os
import zipfile
import shutil
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Dialog"))
        Dialog.resize(747, 462)
        self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(460, 60, 241, 28))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton"))
        self.pushButton_2 = QtGui.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(470, 240, 231, 28))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton_2"))
        self.pushButton_3 = QtGui.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pushButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(270, 400, 181, 51))
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton_3"))
        self.textBrowser = QtGui.QTextBrowser(Dialog)
        self.textBrowser.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 110, 671, 31))
        self.textBrowser.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("textBrowser"))
        self.textBrowser_2 = QtGui.QTextBrowser(Dialog)
        self.textBrowser_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 290, 671, 31))
        self.textBrowser_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("textBrowser_2"))
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.select_source)
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.select_dest)
        self.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.backup)
        self.progress = QtGui.QProgressBar(Dialog)
        self.progress.setGeometry(30, 350, 710, 30)



        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Backup Tool", None))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Select Source", None))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Select Destination", None))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("Dialog", "BackUp Now", None))


    def select_source(self):
        print('Source_selected')
        working_directory =  str(QtGui.QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(Dialog, 'Select USB Drive Location'))
        print(working_directory)  

        self.working_directory = working_directory
        self.textBrowser.setText(working_directory)  




    def select_dest(self):    
        print('dest_selected')
        self.save_name = str(QtGui.QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(Dialog, "Save Project File", "", " Zip File (*.zip)"))
        self.textBrowser_2.setText(self.save_name)  

    def backup(self):
        self.progress.setRange(0,0)
        count = 1
        print('Backup in progress')
        source_folder = self.working_directory
        target_zip = self.save_name
        zipf = zipfile.ZipFile(target_zip, "w")

        for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(source_folder):
            count = count + 1

            #curdir = subdirs.split('\\')[1] #The directory os.walk is currently in.            
            for file in files:
                #print os.path.join(subdir, file)
                QApplication.processEvents()
                zipf.write(os.path.join(subdir, file))
                #print(count)
                #print "Created ", target_zip  

            print('Backup Complete')
            self.progress.setRange(0,100)
        self.progress.setValue(100)





    def docopy(source_folder, target_folder):
        for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(source_folder):
            for file in files:
                #print os.path.join(subdir, file)
                shutil.copy2(os.path.join(subdir, file), target_folder)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Dialog = QtGui.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_Dialog()
    ui.setupUi(Dialog)
    Dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```